# android azure storage API - how to list containers

Tags: android, azure-storage

I'm trying to build an interface that first lists all containers in an azure blob storage account, and then upon selection of a container, navigates to that container and lists the blobs within it.

In order to do that, I must programmatically get a list of all available containers in an account.

I cannot find a `.getContainers()`-or-similar function anywhere. Does it exist? If not, what can I do to list all containers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list containers interface in Android.   The Android interface is nearly identical to Java, so you can *usually* assume support between one and the other. If you see https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobClient.java you'll see the listContainers and listContainersSegmented methods.

Thanks,
Aung

Comment: thanks for your response. are you saying that I should be able to access the method this way?: `blobClient.ListContainers()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use ListContainers() to list all containers in one storage account, the following is the java code:

```html
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
              CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();            
              for(CloudBlobContainer item: blobClient.listContainers())
              {
                  System.out.println(item.getName());
              }
```